# Is there a way to use git merge-base and interactive rebase in one step?

Tags: git

In my git workflow, a common step I take to squash commits is

```
git merge-base HEAD <parent branch>
```

to get the commit hash of the place where my branch forked, then copy and paste that value to use with

```
git rebase -i <hash>
```

I find it easier than manually counting the number of commits to squash. Is there a way to possibly combine the two into one CLI command? Bonus points for if it's without a shell script, but that works too.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work?

```
git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD <parent branch>)
```

$() runs the command in a sub-shell and returns the stdout to git rebase

Comment: Also, if you find yourself doing this a lot for some reason, you can make an alias that uses the same shell feature. A Git alias that begins with `!` runs arbitrary shell commands. Note that if an alias gets complicated, I tend to run my editor on the appropriate Git config file, rather than trying to use `git config` to set it up. If it gets *really* complicated I just write a script anyway :-)